# Как подключиться к БД PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, jdbc

Хочу подключиться к базе `PostgreSQL` через `jdbc`.

Создаю  `connection`

```
 public static Connection getPostgresConnection() {
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) 

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance());

            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();

            url.
                    append("jdbc:postgresql://").  //db type
                    append("localhost:").          //host name
                    append("5432/").               //port
                    append("javaDB?").             //db name
                    append("user=postgres&").      //login
                    append("password=saw123");     //password

            System.out.println("URL: " + url + "\n");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url.toString());
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

вылетает `exception`:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "javaDB" does not
>   exist

вылетает в этой строке

```
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url.toString());
```

в dependency драйвер добавил.
Важно ли где находиться файл с базой?

Comment: у вас БД не существует

Answer (score 6):

Я думаю, что вам стоит перечитать главу Хорстамана про методы и аргументы методов.
Вы должны передать 3 аргумента:

1.`"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/javaDB"`

2.`"postgres"`

2.`"saw123"`

вы же передаете только 1-й и в некорректной форме.
Вы его пытаетесь передать в виде REST запроса.
правильно будет:

```
 Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/javaDB","postgres", "saw123");
```

и заместь .append() проще использовать оператор +, он под капотом сделает тот же аппенд, но читать значительно легче.

Comment: вот то что написано в доке 

'String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret&ssl=true";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)'

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Comment: значит, обратите внимание на передаваемую строку.
сначала попробуйте так, как вам описал я, если эксепшн не кинет, значит с самой БД все ОК и можно дальше экспериментировать.

Comment: Вообще, передавать строку целиком это не очень красиво, плохо читается, а 3 раздельных параметра легко.

Comment: Ошибка оказалась крайней банальной, имя базы было с большой буквы и оно регистро зависимо.

Comment: Хорошо, эксепшн про это и говорил.
Если бы он не мог присоединиться к БД(из-за неправильного адреса), то он бы бросал соответствующий эксепшн.

Answer (score 2):

Неправильная строка для соединения. Она должна быть такого типа:
`"jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password"`.

В Вашем случае:
`"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/javaDB","postgres", "saw123"`.

Сделайте как [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/41444/). Можно и [здесь](http://devcolibri.com/477) посмотреть, но здесь все в одну кучу, с непривычки можно запутаться.

И должно быть настроено подключение с IDE (и обязательно проверьте соединение в ней, postgresql - серверная БД, а не файловая, важен путь к ней, а не файл с базой), и драйвер postrges должен быть и там и в dependency.

Comment: где разница между приведенным вами форматом и сконкатенированной строкой?

Comment: что должно быть "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/javaDB","postgres", "saw123"

Comment: сконкатенированная строка "jdbc:postgresql://localhost5432/javaDB?user=postgres&password=saw123"

Comment: в документации написано так тоже можно https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html